# What are some better options for registering implementations of some abstraction?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, frameworks

It is very often the case where you have many implementations of some sort of abstraction and you need a way to "register" all of them so that other areas of your program, or perhaps another library, can know that they’re available for use.

One option is to designate some type of "master" class in which you instantiate the implementation, provide a reference to the class so that it can be instantiated reflectively, or provide a supplier/function for generating a new instance.

Some people might go this direction by creating a dedicated class and calling it "SomethingManager". Some people might do all of the registrations in the parent class itself. Some people might make an enum. Others use constants. Many pack them into an ever growing method body.

In any case, you end up with the same situation. Where, every time you create a new subclass, you have to go to this designated higher power and add a new line to a never ending laundry list and it ends up looking something like:

```java
register(new Implementation1());
register(new Implementation2());
register(new Implementation3());
// ...
register(new Implementation42());
// To infinity...
```

Or a different combo:

```java
IMPLEMENTATION_1(Implementation1::new),
IMPLEMENTATION_2(Implementation2::new),
IMPLEMENTATION_3(Implementation3::new),
// ...
IMPLEMENTATION_42(Implementation42::new),
// And beyond...
```

Or any other variation of manually typed lists.

Issues with this approach include:

1. It makes it very easy to forget to register a new implementation
2. It is unfriendly to new entrants to your codebase who need to learn where all of the 'master' classes are and what your method is for registration
3. It’s an exceptionally verbose way of saying "register all implementations"
4. It’s unnecessarily redundant

As another approach, rather than requiring that implementers remember to go to some other 'master' class and add a new line, would be to require they remember to put a static member within their implementation which does the registration:

```java
private static final Generator STRUCTURE = Generator.for(Implementation::new);
```

And then you might use com.google.common.reflect to initialize all classes within a designated package and thus prompt their static members to register the implementation:

```java
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    for (ClassPath.ClassInfo info : ClassPath.from(loader).getTopLevelClassesRecursive(package) {
        Class.forName(info.getName());
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to further reduce problem #1 and your abstraction is a parent class, you might require an instance of the implementation’s generator within its constructor, which will give a compiler error if they forget to create one.

However, in exchange for arguably reducing the severity of all 4 problems, it adds the additional problem of fragility, because you’re now dependent upon the package location(s) of the implementations remaining reliable. If it ever changes, there’ll be no obvious errors regarding where the issue is that caused the entire application to suddenly break.

A similar solution which eliminates the need to remember to include a static member would be to use reflection to scan for classes that extend/implement your abstraction and use reflection again for creating new instances. If you want to reduce the performance hit of using reflection for every new instance, you could invest in a LambdaMetaFactory. However, either way it adds more inflexibility regarding the types of constructors that your implementations can contain, and is no less difficult to forget or be unaware of.

So how do we take this a step further and reduce these problems without creating more? Or at the very least, what other options are there, if any?

Answer (score 1):

SPI is the solution: Any 'provider' (implementation) registers itself on its own, by making a text file, available within the classpath (i.e. its inside the same jar the class itself is in), at location `meta-inf/services/com.foo.fully.qualified.name.of.the.interface`, which consists of lines of text: Each line is the FQN of an implementation. They all have a no-args constructor that does nothing.

Java has the 'ServiceLoader' baked in that can load these. It reads out these lines of text and instantiates them all (assuming that there is a no-args constructor that does not crash and each listed class is in fact `implements` or `extends` the thing it's providing).

Since the module system, module-info has this mechanism too (`provides`, I think). I don't think the module system is all that great, so I don't have much personal experience with it.

Comment: Is this not simply another variation of the first solution? i.e providing a laundry list of new lines that specifies each individual implementation. I don’t see how that’s a solution to the problems I mentioned.

Comment: [A] Each implementation can add its classname to its own jar file - you can thus plug in as many implementations as you desire by just sticking jar files on the classpath, in contrast to 'one class with a list' where one would need to recompile that source file every time, and [B] annotation processors can be used to auto-generate that file, at which point all you do to write an impl is to just write a class that extends/implements what you want, tag it with `@Provider`, and be done with it. This is how JDBC finds drivers.

Comment: Whether you’re providing the FQN of the implementations within a single jar or many  independent jars, the problem still remains that every new implementation needs one written out. You’ve just changed the file you need to write them in. With annotation processors, you’re still dependent on the implementor remembering them and manually typing them out, with no compiler warning if they don’t. Effectively, it’s just replacing one easily excluded line of code that needs to be learned, remembered and repeatedly written for another. Granted, the amount of characters in those lines are less.

Comment: If there’s some strategy for using annotation processors which will produce a compiler error if an interface implementor fails to annotate, I’d be interested.

Comment: _an interface implementor fails to annotate_ - why would it? You can implement an interface without intending to be, by default, a 'registered provider'. But you can trivially fork any SPI service file maker tool, they are fairly simplistic.

Comment: If I’m building a framework for a web app and I’ve got some "Entity" abstraction, some "Controller" abstraction maybe even a "Service" abstraction, I’m never going to want a controller, entity or service to *not* be registered. So if I can choose to protect against impls forgetting to annotate and causing bugs that don’t produce errors, or better yet, eliminate the need to remember to redundantly annotate every new impl, then that’s really powerful.

Comment: An AP can detect such situations. I'm not aware of any `@Provider`-style Annotation Processors that do this, but as I said, they aren't particularly complex beasts, it's not hard to add it. Register for the `*` annotation - you get to then inspect all code.

Comment: Ideally, I’m thinking of some annotation one can apply to an abstraction to automatically detect all of its implementations and handle their registration. I’ll take a look and see if its possible. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It just doesn't work that way, @justis. The classloader abstraction mechanism fundamentally does not support any sort of 'list all' concept. Hence, explicitly written lists, or Annotation Processors that produce this list whilst we're in a context that _does_ support a 'list all' operation, which is: At compile/build time.